# Simply Removing A Curve?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this simple operation to work.

```
LineItem Curve = Pane.AddCurve(Name,Data,Color.blue,SymbolType.Diamond);
zgc.Refresh();
```

Now how do I remove the curve I just added?

Pane.CurveList.Remove()?'
If so, how can I set an object equal to an existing curve to use as a parameter of method Remove()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but...

```
Pane.CurveList[ Pane.CurveList.Count - 1  ].Clear();
zgc.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 3):

You pass in a reference to the curve that you created:

```
Pane.CurveList.Remove(Curve);
```

The documentation is available [here](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/M_ZedGraph_CollectionPlus_Remove_1.htm).

Comment: How do I set "Curve" to a specific curve?  Looked at the documentation and couldn't find it.

Comment: When you call 'AddCurve', it returns the Curve that you've just added, so you can keep a reference to that and then pass it into Remove when you're ready to remove it.

Comment: thanks.  My program adds lines through a WinForm, and each time a line is added, it is set to "Curve".  Is there a way to set each line to "Curve[i]" and have i iterate upwards automatically? Or is there a better way (I wouldn't be surprised) to uniquely identify each curve?